# SWIG wrong encoded string crashes Python

Tags: unicode, utf-8, swig, stdstring

I've a problem where all my SWIG wrappers that deals with strings crashes If I pass a wrong encoded string inside a std::string, I mean strings that contains èé and so on, characters valid for the current locale, but not UTF-8 valid.

On my code side, I have solved parsing the input as wide strings and convert them to UTF-8, but I would like to catch those kind of errors with an Exception rather than a crash, isn't supposed PyUnicode_Check to fail with those strings ?

Swig actually crashes in SWIG_AsCharPtrAndSize() when calling PyString_AsStringAndSize(), this is the swig generated code:

```
    SWIGINTERN int
SWIG_AsCharPtrAndSize(PyObject *obj, char** cptr, size_t* psize, int *alloc)
{
#if PY_VERSION_HEX>=0x03000000
#if defined(SWIG_PYTHON_STRICT_BYTE_CHAR)
  if (PyBytes_Check(obj))
#else
  if (PyUnicode_Check(obj))
#endif
#else  
  if (PyString_Check(obj))
#endif
  {
    char *cstr; Py_ssize_t len;
#if PY_VERSION_HEX>=0x03000000
#if !defined(SWIG_PYTHON_STRICT_BYTE_CHAR)
    if (!alloc && cptr) {
        /* We can't allow converting without allocation, since the internal
           representation of string in Python 3 is UCS-2/UCS-4 but we require
           a UTF-8 representation.
           TODO(bhy) More detailed explanation */
        return SWIG_RuntimeError;
    }
    obj = PyUnicode_AsUTF8String(obj);
    if(alloc) *alloc = SWIG_NEWOBJ;
#endif
    PyBytes_AsStringAndSize(obj, &cstr, &len);
#else
    PyString_AsStringAndSize(obj, &cstr, &len);
#endif
    if (cptr) {
```

Crash happens to into the last PyString_AsStringAndSize visible.
I remark that strings are passed as std::string but in happens also with const char* without any kind of difference.

Thanks in advice !

Comment: What version python are you targeting? What version of swig did you use?

Comment: python 3.3 and swig 3.0.12

Comment: So you didn't define PY_VERSION_HEX correctly.

Comment: Can you make a small example of one function and its SWIG .i file that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with 3.3.0 version we were still using, updating to 3.3.7 solved the problem, in the Python release notes there's several bug fixed in regards to PyUnicode_Check

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce.  Edit your question and add a [Minimal, Complete, Verifable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if this example doesn't solve your issue and need further help:

**test.i**

```
%module test

%include <std_string.i>

%inline %{
#include <string>

std::string func(std::string s)
{
    return '[' + s + ']';
}
%}
```

**Demo:**

```
Python 3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:35:05) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> test.func('ábc')
'[ábc]'
```

Comment: it is the way back, we call a base class (in c++) that's overriden by Swig directors. Passing a const char* with non-UTF8 valid characters , crashes Python. For the moment we have solved sanitizing the buffer with a UTF8 check routine, but it's still a bug in Python in my opinion